# Can anyone explain to me what this snippet of code is doing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm using `node.js`, `express.js`, `javascript` and `MongoDB` as database of an existing codebase. I have a model called `Cart` and I'm trying to get some information from my cart with a specified condition like this:

```
var buyerCart = await Cart.findOne({
  buyer: _id,
  seller: product.sellerID,
});
```

After that, I'm creating a new product object that is going to be used to update the existing one in the `Cart` model. The new product looks likes this:

```
    let newProduct = {
      "products.$[product].quantity": quantity,
      "products.$[product].amount": amount,
      "products.$[product].discount": discount,
      "products.$[product].aggregatedAmount": aggr,
      "products.$[product].tax": tax,
      "products.$[product].condition": condition,
      "products.$[product].category": category,
    };
```

Finally here's a script that's updating data in the database:

```
    await buyerCart.update(
      {
        amount: newAgg.toFixed(2),
        totalAmount: newAmnt.toFixed(2),
        totalDiscount: newDsct.toFixed(2),
        totalTax: newTax.toFixed(2),
        totalQuantity: newQty,
        $set: newProduct,
      },
      { arrayFilters: [{ "product.productId": productId }] }
    );
```

PS: All those variables are declared somewhere in my codes.

Now the question is:

> How does that syntax in a new object(`newProduct`) work? It looks
> like `"products.$[product].quantity"` is the object's key and
> `quantity` is the value but the key is in a string form and I think it won't be a valid `script` since they are in quotes. I tried to read the official docs of
> [MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) about using the `$set` operator but can't get it.

Comment: Since you are not sure what your code does, I'm assuming it's not your own. I would recommend rephrasing the question to reflect your actual problem (especially the title). Probably what you are looking for is https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That query uses [array filters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) to determine which object update.

Note how in `newProduct` you are using as key field:

`"products.$[product].quantity": quantity`,

that follows the pattern

`"<array>.$[<identifier>]" : value`.

When you do `$set: newProduct` you are doing a "normal" `$set` in mongo, which receive an object, in this case the object is created before, but look an usual `$set`, for example:

```
model.update({},{ $set: {field:"newValue" })
```

You are only changing`{field:"newValue" }` for your object created before.

And the last field `arrayFilters` is defined into documentation:

```
db.collection.updateMany(
   { <query conditions> },
   { <update operator>: { "<array>.$[<identifier>]" : value } },
   { arrayFilters: [ { <identifier>: <condition> } ] }
)
```

Check [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FNaDqxbA782) example where using `arrayFilters` one product (which match `"product.productId":1`) is updated.

At this point, there are one thing that I don't understand:

Using `update` method it needs three objects (query, update, options), I can't see the query object.

Your update should be something like this:

```
await buyerCart.update(
      {
        amount: newAgg.toFixed(2),
        totalAmount: newAmnt.toFixed(2),
        totalDiscount: newDsct.toFixed(2),
        totalTax: newTax.toFixed(2),
        totalQuantity: newQty
      },
      {
        $set: newProduct,
      },
      { arrayFilters: [{ "product.productId": productId }] }
    );
```

Comment: what's your query object in your case?

Comment: First object into update method: `{amount: newAgg.toFixed(2) , totalAmount: newAmnt.toFixed(2), ...}`

Comment: I have it too. Check above.

Comment: The only difference I see is that you're putting `$set: newProduct` in its own object while for me it's in the `query` object.

Comment: It looks like in the normal `$set` the first object can take a condition, so why would someone use `arrayFilters` instead of the normal set conditions @J.F. ?

Comment: Yes, check the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/). Definition is: `db.collection.update(query, update, options)`. You have to pass at least two first objects (query and update). You can't use `$set` into the first object.

Comment: `arrayFilters`  is used to filter into the array to update desired position.

Comment: That means that this update script doesn't work maybe? I'll have to test it and see.

Comment: `db.alumni.update({ }, { $set : { "degrees.$[degree].gradcampaign" : 1 } },{ arrayFilters : [ {"degree.level" : { $ne: "Bachelor" } } ], multi : true }
)
`
Does this mean that it'll update all fields when you leave the first `query` parameter empty?

Comment: Yes, if first object is empty, the update object will be apply to all documents.